# Quitar buscar de un select de bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

como quitar el buscador de un `select` de **bootstrap**?
[select quitar buscar](https://gyazo.com/711eba160831f0a4e0a658a91e39ac2d)
Solo quiero que aparezca el listado.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label">Talla</label>
            <select class="form-control input-sm selectpicker" name="Datos[plan]" data-error="Es un campo obligatorio" data-live-search="true" required="required" id="plan">                           
                  <option value="1">indistinto</option>
                  <option value="2">5</option>
                  <option value="3">7</option>
                  <option value="4">9</option>
              </select>
          </div>

js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({style: 'btn-success btn-sm',size: 4,noneSelectedText: 'Seleccionar un elemento', liveSearchPlaceholder:'Buscar',noneResultsText: '¡No existe el elemento buscado!',countSelectedText:'{0} elementos seleccionados',actionsBox:true,selectAllText: 'Seleccionar todos',deselectAllText: 'Deseleccionar todos'});
```

librerias

```
    <!-- Bootstrap select js -->
<script src="../../../assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Y si intentas quitándole esto liveSearchPlaceholder:'Buscar', o dejándolo vacío en la configuración que tienes?

Comment: eso es para el placeholder del campo buscar  ¿dejandolo vacio donde?

Comment: Lo que estás diciendo es que quieres quitar ese placeholder no ? si no es eso no entiendo tu pregunta y vacío es esto liveSearchPlaceholder:''

Comment: quitar el search el buscador , lo que tu me dijiste ya lo hice antes y solo quita las palabra de buscar

Comment: Ahhh entiendo, entonces a tu configuración pásale este parámetro: liveSearch: false

Comment: ya quedo de donde puedo obtener los parametros para modificar

Comment: Te voy a publicar la respuesta y te explico mas a fondo, me alegra que te diera !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es simplemente configurar tu `selectpicker` como lo desees, los parámetros de configuración los puedes ver en [Options Bootstrap-Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/)

Ahora para deshabilitar el buscador del `select` utilizaremos el parámetro `liveSearch` y le daremos un valor de `false` y eliminamos el parámetro `liveSearchPlaceholder` por que ya no lo vamos a necesitar, quedando tu código así:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-success btn-sm',
    size: 4,
    noneSelectedText: 'Seleccionar un elemento',
    noneResultsText: '¡No existe el elemento buscado!',
    countSelectedText:'{0} elementos seleccionados',
    actionsBox:true,
    selectAllText: 'Seleccionar todos',
    deselectAllText: 'Deseleccionar todos',
    liveSearch: false
});
```